# Don't know why but Skip not working in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
let data = await Products.find({type})
 .limit(page*No_Of_Products_Per_Page).skip(2);
```

Skip is not working here:- "mongoose": "^6.5.0",

Comment: Can you please define what "not working" actually means?

Comment: It is not skipping returning me let's say page is 3 and No_Of_Products_Per_Page is 4 then 12 elements

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.